# How to debug with Eclipse using GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gcc, hardware

I was setting up my environment to do some development using Eclipse on hardware and  I got stuck on a strange error as I try to run debugging.

```
Error while launching command: arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
```

The weird thing about it is that then I try to run command `arm-none-eabi-gdb --version` on command line it works just fine.
I am new so I don't know what information may be relevant so please ask in comments.

Comment: Figured out that it was a wrong bit version installed on my machine (x32 insted of x64)

Answer (score 0):

On the debug configuration menu -> Debugger -> GDB Commands, Instead of just typing arm-none-eabi-gdb, enter the whole path. Worked for me